# Training loss fluctuates a lot

Tags: tensorflow, training-data

I am fine tuning SSD Mobilenet (COCO)  on Pascal VOC dataset. I have around 17K images in the training set and num_steps is 100000. Details of config are -

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0001
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
}
```

However the training loss fluctuates a lot as shown here [training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQtkn.png)

How can I avoid this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> It seems likely that your learning rate, though you're decaying it, is
>   still too large in later steps.

Things that I recommend at that point would be to:

- Increase your decay
- Try another optimizer (e.g. ADAM which worked good for me in such cases)